# constrain all generic parameters to a single interface c#

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, constraints

I have an abstract class with a few or many (from 1 all the way up to 16) generic parameters like so:

```
public abstract class ComponentSystem<F1> : ComponentSystemBase
    where F1 : IComponent
{ }

public abstract class ComponentSystem<F1, F2, F3, F4> : ComponentSystemBase
    where F1 : IComponent
    where F2 : IComponent
    where F3 : IComponent
    where F4 : IComponent
{ }
```

Is there a short way to write `where F1 : IComponent` for all generic parameters so i don't have to do for all generic parameters by hand. Because with 16 parameters this becomes rather ugly.

If something is unclear let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: one class as `ComponentSystem<IEnumerable<F>> : ComponentSystemBase where F : IComponent` or even  `ComponentSystem<IEnumerable<IComponent>> : ComponentSystemBase`... but of course it depends on what you wana imlement (F1...FN usage)

Comment: @Selvin I am quite new to generics and c# programming could you maybe elaborate a bit more? maybe with an example? Of how this would work / implemented?

Comment: show example of how you are using those generic parameters in `ComponentSystem` without it is just hard to say if you can use IEnumerable/List or not

Comment: Cool i will cook up an use-case example! probably only have time later tonight :/

Comment: If `F1, F2, F3, F4` are all of type `IComponent` then there is little point for `F2, F3, F4`.  Just use `F1`

Comment: @MickyD: that's not necessarily so. E.g. maybe the broader types as designed don't distinguish between different kinds of `IComponent`, but there are still different ones the class needs to know about. It would be better to refine the types as declared (of course, one would still be stuck with four different constraints in that case), but that's not always going to be possible.